# Can't install Sphinx for OS X 10.9.5: '"/lib/cpp" fails sanity check'

Tags: php, c++, macos, osx-mavericks, sphinx

I've installed the developer tools, restarted my machine, installed a separate g++ compiler, etc but running `./configure` still fails with this error: `error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check` Any tips in the right direction to install the /lib/cpp directory? Thanks!

Also here's part of the log that may be helpful:

```
configure:4459: checking how to run the C++ preprocessor
configure:4490:  -E  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4491: -E: command not found
configure:4496: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4490:  -E  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4491: -E: command not found
configure:4496: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4490: /lib/cpp  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4491: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory
configure:4496: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4490: /lib/cpp  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4491: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory
configure:4496: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4573: result: /lib/cpp
configure:4597: /lib/cpp  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4598: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory
configure:4603: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4597: /lib/cpp  conftest.cc
./configure: line 4598: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory
configure:4603: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libsphinxclient"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libsphinxclient 0.0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:4672: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See 'config.log' for more details.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CXXCPP="gcc -E" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

via http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/installing-sphinx-and-pecl-sphinx-on-mac-os-x.html